# Filtering the_content, but still need to display the unfiltered content inside filter

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I'm working on a plugin that creates and displays Custom Post Types. I'm using ACF for additional fields.

Problem comes when I need to add the actual content into the filter. There's a slideshow in the normal wysiwyg editor that needs to be displayed there. See screengrab.

Is there a way to have the_content be displayed inside a filter that is using the_content?
Or is there a different way of coding this?

Here is my code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'fds_the_content');
function fds_the_content( $content ) {

    if (is_singular( 'services' ) && in_the_loop()) {
        ob_start(); ?>

        <div class="fds-top">

                    <div id="top-content" class="contain-columns">

                        <div id="portfolio" class="m-all t-2of3 d-3of4 gl">

                            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <div class="slideshow">

                                <section class="entry-content cf">
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </section> <!-- end article section -->

                            </div>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>

                            <?php else : ?> 

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div> <!-- end #portfolio -->
                        <div class="2-percent"></div> <!-- What a hack! -->
                        <div id="service-sidebar" class="m-all t-1of3 d-1of4 gl">

                            <h2>Recent 
                                    <?php
                                $category = get_the_category(); 
                                echo $category[0]->cat_name;
                                    ?>                                                      
                            </h2>

                            <?php 
                                global $post;
                                $categories = get_the_category();
                                foreach ($categories as $category) :
                                ?>

                                <?php
                                    // The Query
                                    $the_query = new WP_Query( 

                                        array( 
                                            'posts_per_page' => 2,
                                            'category__and' => array( $category->term_id ) ) );
                                ?>  
                                <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>


                                <!-- the loop -->
                                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                                    <a class="recent-post" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                                        <div class="recent-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></div>
                                        <h3 class="recent-blog-title-desktop"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>                    
                                    </a>                                                

                                <?php endwhile;  
                                    wp_reset_query(); ?>
                                    <!-- end of the loop -->

                                    <!-- pagination here -->
                                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                                <?php else:  ?>
                                  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>



                            <?php endforeach; ?>    

                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div id="midriff" class="contain-columns">

                    <div id="service-info" class="m-all t-all d-all gl">
                        <header class="article-header">
                            <h1 class="single-title custom-post-type-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        </header>

                        <section class="entry-content cf">

                            <div class="segment">
                                <div class="segment-photo-left">
                                    <?php 
                                    $image = get_field('general_photo');
                                    $size = 'medium'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                                    if( $image ) {
                                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="segment-text"><?php the_field('general_info'); ?></div> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="segment">
                                <h2>Rates</h2>
                                <div class="segment-photo-right">
                                    <?php 
                                    $image = get_field('rates_photo');
                                    $size = 'medium'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                                    if( $image ) {
                                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="segment-text"><?php the_field('rates'); ?></div>    
                            </div>

                            <div class="segment">
                                <h2>Areas Served</h2>
                                <div class="segment-photo-left">
                                    <?php 
                                    $image = get_field('areas_served_photo');
                                    $size = 'medium'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                                    if( $image ) {
                                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="segment-text"><?php the_field('areas_served'); ?></div> 
                            </div>  

                            <div class="segment">
                                <h2>Kind Words</h2>

                                    <?php 

                                    // args
                                    $args = array(
                                        'posts_per_page'    =>  1,
                                        'post_type'         =>  'reviews',
                                        'meta_key'          =>  'review',
                                        'orderby'           =>  'rand'
                                    );

                                    // get results
                                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                    // The Loop
                                    ?>
                                    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                                        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                                            <blockquote>

                                                <?php the_field('review'); ?>

                                            </blockquote>   
                                            <h3 class="client-sig">~<?php the_field('review_client_name'); ?></h3>  
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>

                            </div>  

                            <div class="segment">
                                <h2>Contact</h2>
                                <div class="segment-photo-right">
                                    <?php 
                                    $image = get_field('contact_photo');
                                    $size = 'medium'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                                    if( $image ) {
                                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="segment-text"><?php the_field('contact'); ?></div>  
                            </div>

                        </section>

                    </div> <!-- End #service-info -->

                </div>      

                </div>

            </div>


        <?php
        echo ob_get_clean();    
    }
        return $content;
}
```

[image: This shows the output from above code]

Answer (score 1):

First, your filter should return, not echo anything. The content will appear in the wrong place if you echo directly within the function.

The original contents of `the_content` are passed to the filter function as an argument-

```
function fds_the_content( $content ) { // <--- original value of the_content
    // append original $content
    $new_content = 'new content' . $content;
    return $new_content;
}
```

EDIT- echo `$content` in an output buffer-

```
function fds_the_content( $content ) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div>
        <h4>Some Markup</h4>
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_filter('the_content', 'fds_the_content');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Wouldn't that just append the content to the new content? I'm hoping to have the original content inside the new content.

Comment: you can insert `$content` anywhere you want it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. How do I get the original contents to display _inside_ the code that I have?

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either...
Here's a live example: http://aaronandwhitney.com/services/kansas-city-wedding-photography/

I used the echo and that doesn't seem to be doing anything...
Is this possible to do? Or does it have to be recoded somehow?

Comment: Here's a pastebin with the modified code:
(http://pastebin.com/0p6uVRt6)

Comment: take the loop out of there, you're already in the loop, it's probably breaking things.

Comment: That was it!!! Thanks for looking at that. What a relief!
Didn't even think of the Loop being the issue!

Thanks again!